# empty content tree pickers in Umbraco 6.2.4

Tags: umbraco6

I am experiencing some problems concerning empty content tree pickers. I'm running umbraco 6.2.4 in IIS7 (sql server 2008). I have a page with several content tree pickers (with the same dataType) and one of them is not showing any content (not always the same contentPicker interestingly).

In my debuggers network section the call to get the data for the content picker keeps pending (/umbraco/webservices/treeclientservice.asmx/getinitapptreedata) Deleting the TEMP directory, recycling the app pool, changing the doc type or dataType does not solve the problem. Is anyone experiencing similar problems or know how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yep, I have seen this...not sure how I solved it, maybe with a republish all.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your content cache is corrupted somehow? Right click on the content folder in the CMS and select "Republish site" that should clear the cache. See if that solves your problem.